# Bootstrap Popover - Empty space at top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

I am using angular bootstrap to create a popover.

For some reason there is a lot of space left at the top of the popover when popover is created. Please check the image attached.

Grayed rectangle is my text [I have to keep it hidden] and you can see lot of blank space at the top of rectangle. I am not sure what css styling is causing it.

These are the only concerned CSS styling of popover.

```
.popover {
    white-space: pre-wrap !important;
}


.popover-content {
    color: black !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Update:

Here is the live [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bHbBwZpv5YZLVd6W9q1v?p=preview)

I know it is pre-wrap that is causing it, what I want is popover text aligned at center, wrapped at new line and not overflowing the popver window.

[image]

Comment: any url to check or jsfiddle example to see the issue without that cannot help?

Comment: agree with @NadeemmnnMohd, it is impossible to answer without a code example and/or a proof of error in a fiddle, plunker or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with CSS

```
.popover {
    white-space: pre-wrap !important;
}
```

change to

```
.popover {
white-space: normal !important;
word-break: break-all!important;
```

}

then works fine

Comment: I would like to keep new lines, with your solution new lines are scrapped.

Answer (score 0):

Put the white-space rule on the .popover-content (not on .popover)

```
.popover-content {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```